# VS Code/Prettier not inserting new line and indent on return in HTML and JS

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I am using Prettier in VS Code on a Mac. When I press enter after typing curly braces or parantheses on line 1, I would expect the closing brace/parenthesis to be moved to line 3 and  my cursor to be placed at the correct indentation on line 2.

This works in the [Prettier Playground](https://prettier.io/playground/), but not in VS Code (see screen recordings).

I should mention that it does work in VS Code in HTML, when I press enter between opening and closing tags, but it does not work in CSS or JavaScript.

I have tried to disable all extensions and reinstalled Prettier, but to no avail.

Anyone have a solution for this?

Screen recordings:

[Prettier Playground behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXQT7.gif)

[VS Code behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TK9J.gif)

Comment: The formatting is applied in VS Code only when you call "Format". Usually you will just enable "Format on Save". I suggest you look into that settings (I'm not sure about the shortcut keys, because I'm on PC)

Comment: I have format on save enabled, and that does work. However, it should also do what I described above when I hit enter. It does work in the Prettier Playground, and I've seen it work that way in many video tutorials as well. I don't know if it's something Prettier does, or whether it's a setting in VS Code itself, or some other plugin, but it does work for some people, and I would like to know what I have to do to enable it on my machine.

Comment: Well, you could enable "Format On Type" in VS Code Options, probably it's exactly what you're asking for. I would not enable it, but YMMV. If you really want to, it's there for you to use.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't change the behaviour either.

Comment: Please keep in mind that Prettier will format your document only if the syntax is correct. If anything is off, he will not be able to parse and rewrite the document.

Comment: Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: Thanks for contributing this idea – it didn't solve my problem but I had not been aware of this command before :-)